# Oracle12c db listener multiple errors

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I've installed Oracle12c on a virtual machine, in a second virtual drive that is mounted on /media. When I access there, I go to ORACLE_HOME/bin and try to initialize lsnrctl, but it keeps throwing this error:

[image]

And this one if I try to start it:

[image]

Here you have my listener.ora file, changed it many times but it never avoided the error:

[image]

What should I do, so the listener begins to work proper?

Comment: First thing, does `tnsping` work? Are you sure the privileges are correctly set? Who owns the Oracle binaries? Did you set it up as `oracle` user? If yes, then you need to start the listener as oracle user. Other users might not have the privilege.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. My oracle account has all privileges and access to the oracle DB files, so there shouldn't be any error there. I always log into oracle to try to start the listener, but it just won't work.

Comment: To connect locally on the database server you do not need a listener. Only when you have to receive remote connections listener is needed. So could you try connecting locally?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have exported your ORACLE_HOME environment variable. It may be set in the current shell (even that isn't clear) but it won't be available to child processes and applications unless it is exported. e.g.:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/media/OracleVol/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1`
```

You probably also want to add `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` to your PATH environment variable too.

It is common to set these kinds of things in your shell login file, and Oracle installs a global script (under `/usr/local/bin`, and also under each ORACLE_HOME) called `oraenv` which you can source to set things up:

```
. oraenv
```

Note the period so that it is sourced into the currently shell; if you just run it as a script the changes won't stick. You'll need to supply the ORACLE_SID of the instance you're working with - the `oraenv` script will call `dbhome` which looks up that SID in your `oratab` file.